# GraphQL query with multiple nested resolvers and mapping fields to arguments

Tags: graphql

From GraphQL Client's perspective, how do I perform a query with multiple nested resolvers where the fields from the parent are passed as arguments to the child resolver?

Here is a minimal example:

#### GraphQL Schema:

```
type Author {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type Book {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  releaseDate: String!
}


type Query {
  // Returns a list of Authors ordered by name, 'first' indicates how many entries to return
  getAllAuthors(first: Int!): [Author]!
  // Returns a list of Books ordered by releaseDate, 'first' indicates how many entries to return
  getBooksByAuthorId(first: Int! authorId: ID!): [Book]!
}
```

Is it possible to write a query to get all authors and their last released book? Something around the lines:

```
query GetAuthorsWithLastBook($first: Int!) {
  getAllAuthors(first: $first) {
    authorId: id
    name
    lastBook: getBooksByAuthor(1, authorId) {
      title
    }
  }
}
```

In the example above, I attempted to alias `getAllAuthors.id` as `authorId` and pass the alias down as argument to `getBooksByAuthor(...)` but that didn't work.

The key aspect of the problem is that I don't know the `authorId`s beforehand. I could fetch the authors first and build a query to fetch their last book but that will result in multiple queries and that is something I would like to avoid.

### Update

A Java Kickstarter example is available here: https://www.graphql-java-kickstart.com/tools/schema-definition/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, on the graphql definition, you need to add `lastBook` in the Author

```
type Author {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  lastBook: [Book]
}
```

Next up u need to write the resolver for the `lastBook`

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    Author {
      lastBook: (parent, args) {
        const userId = parent.id;
        return getBooksByAuthor(userId, 1);
      },
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes. That worked well, thanks. I am using Java Kickstarter implementation and after a lot of digging I was able to find some references in their documentation. https://www.graphql-java-kickstart.com/tools/schema-definition/